# QGIS imports two excel double vectors: one as double, the other as QString! Why?

Tags: qgis, import, excel

I work in QGIS 2.8.3 and import an excel file (xlsx version 2013) containing 5 vectors: string, string, double, int, double. All vectors have a heading. However, QGIS tells me that the last double vector is imported as a QString. I also tried to use rounded values and import them as ints, copy everything as value into a brand new file, but to no avail.

I know that you can force QGIS to import vectors from CSV-files as predefined variable types, but I don't want to use CSV-files, and I particularly want to know why it does import one double as double and another double as QString. Is it a bug? If so, when does it occur?

Comment: Do some of your doubles have negative (-) signs?

Comment: Yes they do. Should that make a difference? I can calculate with them, so Excel interprets them as double, not as string/text.

Comment: The issue is not how Excel interprets your values, but how the QGIS importation tool does. It is possible (but not 100% sure) that this tool is flawed and interprets negative signs as text, thus importing the whole column as QString.